# Is there a way to communicate rest api's that are launched using containers?

Tags: docker, http, docker-compose, fastapi, firewalld

I've been trying to send an http post request to a container on the same network but the host refused to connect. Here are the results that I got after debugging:

- The containers can ping each other.
- I can access both of the containers using REST communication from my machine.
- Other protocoles, AMQP and RPC communications work fine.
- The request raises an error: [Error 111]: the host refused to connect.
- I found some solutions that involve the firewall policies, tried them and it didn't work either.

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
- Containers: Uvicorn server using fastapi.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your host has a DNS name that both containers can resolve, the easiest way is to bind both containers to the host's network using `--net=host`.

You can get away with binding the consuming service to `--net=host` and `--publish`'ing the port of the producing service.

The problem is that the containers are running in separate network namespaces and you need something (e.g. the host's network) to act as the shared namespace.

Another solution is if your host has a DNS that's resolvable by the consuming container and then you can reference the producing service's port(s) using the host's DNS name and the host's port when the producing container's port(s) are being forwarded.